# Unreadable text at native resolution 2560x1440

Tags: graphics-card, display, resolution, amd-radeon, high-resolution

I have a BenQ GW2765HT monitor ([specifications](http://www.benq.com/product/monitor/gw2765ht/specifications/)) connected to an AMD Radeon R5 230 graphics card ([specifications](https://www.asus.com/Graphics-Cards/R5230SL2GD3L/specifications/), driver: 15.200.1046.0). When I change the resolution to the native monitor resolution of 2560x1440 the text is unreadable. Why? Do I have to change the graphics card? If yes, what should I look for?

OS: Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1. Cable: DVI-D Single Link.

Comment: Single-Link DVI can’t do 2560x1440. Are you sure it’s a Single-Link cable?

Comment: With which resolution is the text readable? And which text - desktop or programs?

Comment: @DanielB https://pasteboard.co/GGFYXtJ.png https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#/media/File:DVI_Connector_Types.svg

Comment: @harrymc 1920x1080, desktop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re using a Single-Link DVI cable. This is not enough for 2560×1440@60Hz:

> Single link DVI employs a single 165 MHz transmitter that supports resolutions up to 1920 × 1200 at 60 Hz.

([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#Connector))

You’ll have to get a Dual-Link cable. IIRC there’s no way of detecting the cable type, so the monitor just won’t receive all the data, resulting in a corrupted image.

Answer (score 0):

Use another cable.

Duel link DVI or DisplayPort

[DVI single link support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface)
(1440 × 900) @ 60 Hz.

Answer (score 0):

I have found [an article](https://www.dewitcomputers.nl/info.asp?id=A40757)
(Dutch) where it says this about your graphic adapter:

```
Maximale resolutie:     2560x1600 (WQXGA)
```

According to Wikipedia in [Digital Visual Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface), WQXGA is a display mode available in dual link
only.

If you are using a single-link DVI cable, and your card can only achieve
the resolution of 2560x1440 using WQXGA which is a dual-link mode,
then it is clear where is the problem.